# d3 Linear Scale not uniform

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, scale

Super new to d3. This is my first linear-scale chart. Why the value 20 on the y-axis not scaled uniformly?
 [Full code](https://blockbuilder.org/KushagraPan/f9149dcea5ccb9002cfd0287a243c3b3)

Also, why is the last month missing in x-axis and last value missing in y-axis

[image: Chart]

Comment: That axis is perfectly uniform. By the way, that code is far from full.

Comment: Code is complete now. The distance between 0 and 20 could be more, no?

Comment: What zero? That first tick is not zero, that's the minimum in the data, you're using `d3.extent`.